# Insert is a variable but is used like a method - calling class1 from Main Class

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to call class1.cs in Main Class, SQL command parameter, but I getting the error. I am working from my previous thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705969/can-i-call-a-sql-command-parameter-from-another-class)
I would be grateful if anyone can help me out here, thanks in advance..

class.cs

```
 public static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var myCon = new OleDbConnection();
        myCon.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  
        Source=C:\...Database1.mdb";
        return myCon;
    }

    public static void Insert(string id, string agegroup, string gender, string crimoff, string photoa, string cv)
    {

        var con = GetConnection();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, AgeGroup, Gender, CriminalOffence, photo, CV )";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeGroup", agegroup);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CriminalOffence", crimoff);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photoa);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CV", cv);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Main Form class where I am getting error...

```
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Class1 Insert = new Class1();
        Insert(textBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, rBYes.Text, rBNo.Text, // error pointing at Insert line
        pictureBox1.Image, richTextBox1.Text);

        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            //using MemoryStream:
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo_aray);
        }
```

Comment: Try `Class1.Insert(therest`... It's a static method.

Comment: @MartinMulder - Damith solution worked but I got error for pictureBox1.Image...Argument 5: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'string'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to create object to call static  method. if the method is on same namespace you can call direct method like below.

```
Insert(textBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, rBYes.Text, rBNo.Text, 
        pictureBox1.Image, richTextBox1.Text);
```

But change the name of the object you created as `Insert`

```
Class1 Insert = new Class1(); // remove this line
```

If your method `Insert` written inside `Class1`, then you can call it as below

```
Class1.Insert(textBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, rBYes.Text, rBNo.Text, 
        pictureBox1.Image, richTextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: thanks Damith, that solved the problem. I got error for pictureBox1.Image...Argument 5: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'string'. Shall I create another thread?

Comment: Yes, create new question.

Comment: Thanks Damith. your solution has worked.

Answer (score 0):

- Your Insert-method is a static method. I have the feeling you should put that classname in front of it.
- Your Insert-method has 6 parameters, but you try to push in 7 arguments.
- Your arguments are not all of type string. One is of type Image.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you created a variable named Insert immediately before you tried to call the Insert function.  The compiler is seeing the variable and attempting to use it as a function - which can't be done in this case.

You don't actually need to create the instance of Class1 - as the other posters have said - because the Insert function is static.