# Argument 5: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'string' - calling class1 from Main Class

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I am working from my previous thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266771/insert-is-a-variable-but-is-used-like-a-method-calling-class1-from-main-cl#16266868). I am getting this error. I don't know how to solve this problem. I am trying to call class1.cs in Main class. Most appreciate if anyone can help me here. thanks in advance...

this is class1.cs

```
public static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    var myCon = new OleDbConnection();
    myCon.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  
    Source=C:\...Database1.mdb";
    return myCon;
}

public static void Insert(string id, string agegroup, string gender, string photoa)
{

    var con = GetConnection();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, AgeGroup, Gender, photo )";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeGroup", agegroup);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photoa);

    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

this is my Main class where I would like to call it.

```
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Class1.Insert(textBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, pictureBox1.Image); // error is pointing at picture1.Image
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            //using MemoryStream:
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo_aray);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is you sending Image but your method accepting string type

```
public static void Insert(string id, string agegroup, string gender, System.Drawing.Image photoa)
{
   // code 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", imageToByteArray(photoa));
   // code 
}

public static byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image iImage)  
{  
    MemoryStream mMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();  
    iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);  
    return mMemoryStream.ToArray();  
}
```

Comment: thanks for fast response. I am in a limbo here. Jon Skeet has been given a reality check and advise about the insert functionality. Then on the hand should I ask about the error of... An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WFATest1.Class1.imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image)

Comment: @bucketblast - In order to call imageToByteArray from your Insert method, it needs to be static.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes - your last parameter is declared like this:

```
string photoa
```

... but you're calling it with an argument of `picture1.Image`, which isn't a string. What text are you trying to store in the database? Or if you're trying to store the image data itself, why have you declared a parameter of type `string`?

We can tell you what's *wrong*, but you'll need to work out for yourself how you want to fix it, because we don't know your requirements. You *may* want to write the image to a stream, and store the binary data in the database. Or maybe you just want to store a filename in the database.

As an aside, given this question and your last one, I would strongly suggest that you take a step back and learn C# from the basics, rather than diving into GUIs and databases. It's much easier to cope with the more complicated matters later if you have a really firm grasp of the language to start with. I suggest you start with console-based apps working with core elements of the framework - collections, file IO etc. Experiment with aspects of the language (and object orientation in general) such as inheritance, overloading etc. Then when you're confident about these building blocks, you'll be in a much better position to work in more challenging situations. It's unfortunate that some books throw beginners into the deep end by *starting off* with databases and UIs :(

Comment: I would like to store images. I thought perhaps I need to use byte instead of string but that didn't work. I will edited my thread at the top to show you what I mean

Comment: @bucketblast: By the time the `Insert` call returns, the insert has already happened, and `cmd` is out of scope. As I say, I strongly recommend that you take a step back - just trying random things without really understanding what's going on isn't going to help you.

Comment: I understand what you. I can use these functionality in the Main class and I just want to know how this is done with other classes. but thanks for your advise. I am looking at java data structures and algorithms book, hopefully will help me out

Comment: @bucketblast: It's not data structures and algorithms that's the problem here - it's simply C#.

Comment: May I ask you what you mean by "given this question and your last one". Do you mean by this particular topic or you do not wish for me ask questions in future?

Comment: @bucketblast: I just mean that both questions basically show that you're a bit out of your depth at the moment, and would benefit from going back to the basics.