# Pass byte[] as Parameter to ReportViewer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I have got this line of code to load the image from Sql Database:

```
MemoryStream mem;
    void zobraz_logo()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("SELECT logo FROM firma WHERE id = 1", spojeni));
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();


            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);


            if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
                data = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"]);
                 mem = new MemoryStream(data);

            }

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("");
        }

    }
```

Now I'm trying to pass it as parameter to ReportViewer:

```
eportParameter[] parameter = new ReportParameter[18];

            parameter[18] = new ReportParameter("rp_logo", Image.FromStream(mem)); // this is the issue line


            this.firmaTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataset_voucher.firma);
            this.zajezdTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataset_voucher.zajezd,vybrana_akce,klientClass.Rocnik());


            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


        }
```

I'm trying to load image as parameter to Image of the ReportViewer I hope it is possible do it this way. If not May you please propose me the best way to do that?

On the mentioned line I'm receiving error: `Argument 2:cannot convert from System.Drawing.Image to String[]`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Argument 5: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'string' - calling class1 from Main Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267104/argument-5-cannot-convert-from-system-drawing-image-to-string-calling-cla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, as you can see the `ReportParameter` accepting string, string array and boolean, as you can see in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportparameter.reportparameter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

you should use one of them.

i don't know what the image is for, but you can use it's path in the report

```
parameter[18] = new ReportParameter("rp_logo", new string[]{dataImage});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I tried what you proposed lie this :  parameter[18] = new ReportParameter("rp_logo", dataImage); (passing the original 'data' as in my question) but still got error: cannot convert byte[] to string [] . Would you please help me converting the dataImage to string [] please?

Comment: thanks again but the still occurs. When I simply copy what you proposed. Don't you please know why? I made it like this:  Byte[] dataImage; and copied your edited answer.

Comment: @Marek o so you are using a Byte array... unfortunately there is no constructor to Byte array... you'll have to convert to string

Comment: Oh, I tried the string array but when passing it I receive null exception. Even that I  created parameter with the name same name when passing and created Expresion in the ImageFeild as a reference to this Parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I never used the report viewer but in Crystal report you create the parameter / field as object type and you pass a `byte[]` to that parameter / field.